# how apply conditional statement on sql query result in python

Tags: python, mysql, database-connection

In python , i want to apply following if condition on mysql result. but it is not able to compare the result, what i do??
In this code there is table named as 'mansih' but still it's not printing 'hello'.

```
dir=ptr.execute('show tables')
for i in ptr.fetchall():
    print(i)
    if i== 'mansih':
        print('hello')
```

the output of this code just printing the result of `print(i)`. output is

```
('3432fddf',)
('dgdfdf232342334243432',)
('man456',)
('mansih',)
```

here i expect to print `hello` but it's not printed. so please provide any solution using which i can check whether given touple exist in database or not.

Comment: Just to be sure: is "mansih" not misspelled? I see that your name on this website is "Manish", so with 'i' and 's' switching places. Beyond that: do you see "mansih" being printed at all as part of this loop, just no "hello"? (It could be helpful if you provided your output in addition to the code.)

Comment: no no ,everything right. i created a set of tables one of them  named as "mansih" and i just applying if condition , when mansih found it print hello. but if condition not executing

Comment: Does `if i[0] == 'mansih':` work?  `fetchall` returns a list of _tuples_.

Comment: @snakecharmerb  here i'm using for loop in which each  i represent tuple value , so i think there is no need of using  i[0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in your comment:

```
('3432fddf',) ('dgdfdf232342334243432',) ('man456',) ('mansih',)
```

You get tuples, and not strings, from fetchall. It should work if you modify it to `if i[0] == 'mansih':`, so as to fetch the first element of the tuple – which is the string you expect.

Two important lessons from this are:

1. You can use the (interactive, optionally) interpreter to test your outputs, and you should make sure that you understand what you see. This could spare you lots of head scratching.
2. [Take a look at documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-fetchall.html) if something doesn't work as expected, to make sure you understand how your tools work.

Comment: oh yeah....you're right, thanku so much it's working. but i still don't undderstand why we use i[0] ? can we use anything else like i[1] or i[2]?

Comment: You're welcome! Basically, `fetchall` returns rows; each row can have various columns. In your case, you only have one: the table name; but the interface supports multiple rows. For this reason, `fetchall` returns tuples – think of those as "unchangeable lists". What you want to do here is access the first (and only, in this case) column: the table name; hence, `i[0]`.

Comment: If, instead, your query was `'select name, age from users'`, you could for instance receive an output such as: `('John Smith', 42), ('Kyle Katarn', 35)`, and then `i[0]` could be 'John Smith' (the name) and `i[1]` could be 42 (the age), if we're looking at the first tuple.

Comment: Did you understand the point regarding `i[0]`?